# Calculating 0's and 1's in PHP

Tags: php

I want to calculate Frequency (Monobits) test in PHP:

> Description: The focus of the test is
>   the proportion of zeroes and ones for
>   the entire sequence. The purpose of
>   this test is to determine whether that
>   number of ones and zeros in a sequence
>   are approximately the same as would be
>   expected for a truly random sequence.
>   The test assesses the closeness of the
>   fraction of ones to ½, that is, the
>   number of ones and zeroes in a
>   sequence should be about the same.

I am wondering that do I really need to calculate the 0's and 1's (the bits) or is the following adequate:

```
$value = 0;

// Loop through all the bytes and sum them up.
for ($a = 0, $length = strlen((binary) $data); $a < $length; $a++)
    $value += ord($data[$a]);

// The average should be 127.5.
return (float) $value/$length;
```

If the above is not the same, then how do I exactly calculate the 0's and 1's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you really need to check all zeroes and ones. For example, take the following binary input:

```
01111111 01111101 01111110 01111010
```

. It is clearly (literally) one-sided(8 zeroes, 24 ones, correct result 24/32 = 3/4 = 0.75) and therefore not random. However, your test would compute `125.0 /255` which is close to ½.

Instead, count like this:

```
function one_proportion($binary) {
    $oneCount = 0;
    $len = strlen($binary);
    for ($i = 0;$i < $len;$i++) {
        $intv = ord($binary{$i});
        for ($bitp = 0;$bitp < 7;$bitp++) {
            $oneCount += ($intv>>$bitp) & 0x1;
        }
    }
    return $oneCount / (8 * $len);
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see the second part of your question - how to actually calculate. Updated.